# Meteor deployed on server, but browser says site can't be reached

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I've deployed my meteor app, and have it up and running on an instance.

I've used the following environment variables:

```
MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor'
ROOT_URL='http://<my static ip>'
PORT=3000
```

And I run the program using the following command:

```
node bundle/main.js
```

It prints my `"Meteor is starting up"` that is printed using the `console.log` command, and then doesn't error out, but when I navigate to `http://< my static ip >:3000` in a browser, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` result.

My open mongod terminal says it's connecting fine to the MongoDB database.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to start debugging this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean you deployed it? It looks like you're running it on localhost.

Comment: I'm running the database on localhost of my cloud instance, and then the actual app on a static ip.

Comment: I've opened up all traffic to my IP and I'm still getting no response. Any ideas? My node logs indicate that the server is up and running. I've tried using PORT 80 and 443 as the ENV var

Answer (score 1):

In server you don't need to run meteor application on port 3000. You can run it on port 80 if the port is not being used by any other program.

If you are using port 80 make sure port 80 is opened by the network security rules.

If you are using port 3000 or any other port you will have to make sure that port is opened by the network security rules as above. Additionally you will have to mention the IP in your url, like  `http://<your_ip>:<port>`

Comment: I was going to use port 80, but when I navigate to it, it gives me the nginx welcome page, even though I've uninstalled all nginx from the instance.